# CakePHP 1.2 - Custom IDs for Input Groups?

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox

I'm trying to fix code from a previous programmer, but Cake's FormHelper just doesn't want to make it easy...

We have multiple groups of checkboxes on the same page. To set those up we use the formhelper, as you can see here:

```
echo $form->input("tabs.".$type.".".$value['value'],array('label' => 'Market by '.$namex.'','options'=>$my_all_tabs,'default'=>'SELECT '.$type.'','size'=>10, 'multiple'=> 'checkbox','div'=>'scroll_checkboxes'));
```

The problem is, because of the auto-generated ID format for the checkboxes ($my_all_tabs), the same checkbox in all groups of checkboxes has the same ID... so say I tried checking off the first checkbox in the 3rd group, it would change the first checkbox in the first group.

Here's the HTML output...Bear in mind, there's a couple of these chunks, the number 57 varies depending on which block you're in. But this variable doesn't carry over to the checkbox IDs, causing duplicates

```
    <div class="scroll_checkboxes">
    <label for="TabsOMBCODE57">Market by OMB Market Definition</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[tabs][OMBCODE][57]" value="">  
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[tabs][OMBCODE][57][]" id="TabsOMBCODE1" value="1">
        <label for="TabsOMBCODE1">MEDIAOVERVIEW</label>
    </div>  
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[tabs][OMBCODE][57][]" id="TabsOMBCODE2" value="2">
        <label for="TabsOMBCODE2">ONLINEOVERVIEW</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[tabs][OMBCODE][57][]" id="TabsOMBCODE3" value="3">
        <label for="TabsOMBCODE3">MARKETONLINEDASH</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[tabs][OMBCODE][57][]" id="TabsOMBCODE4" value="4">
        <label for="TabsOMBCODE4">USAVGCOMPARE</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I need that 57 from the name attribute to be in the id attribute as well.

I've tried using the following code to make custom IDs for each one:

```
                                foreach($alltabs as $a){
                                    $my_all_tabs[] = array("name"=>$a,
                                                            "value"=>$count+1,
                                                            "id"=>"willynilly"
                                                            );
                                    $count++;
                                }
```

But that just flat out doesn't work. CakePHP's brilliant system completely ignores the custom id tag.

Is there any solution here that doesn't involve upgrading CakePHP?

Comment: You are doing `"value"=>$count+1,` in the array. Why `$count++` again?

Comment: The count++ was in there first, $count+1 was just added to bump it from starting at 0 to 1. It's really irrelevant to the main issue.

Comment: I pointed it out because the way it is, it seems to me like it will be something like 1,3,5,7, etc... .. no big deal, I just wanted to point that out

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have no way to test this for you as I do not have CakePHP 1.2 setup nor I have ever worked with it.

```
echo $form->input(
    "tabs.".$type.".".$value['value'],
    array(
        'id' => "Tabs".$type.$value['value'],
        'label' => 'Market by'.$namex.'',
        'options'=>$my_all_tabs,
        'default'=>'SELECT '.$type.'','size'=>10, 
        'multiple'=> 'checkbox',
        'div'=>'scroll_checkboxes'
    )
);
```

Comment: You can also review the documentation if you run into other problems relating to the version of CakePHP. I would really advise you upgrade and start using version 3.0. At that point you will need to just start new. A successful upgrade is very hard.

Comment: That's just changing the ID of the "parent" input, I guess I should have shown more of the html output... I'll edit to include that.

Unfortunately this is a pretty major web-app for my company and while we have plans to build out a new version in the next year or so, I can't ignore the issue and I also can't scrap the existing app to start fresh.

Comment: I actually think you should show more of your view code where you are using your form helper. If you are looping and use the $form[input] above it should change for all of them. Place your controller code, not just that one `echo` and I will try to help you further